# What is the probability of at least one coincidence after a permutation?

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, permutations

Imagine we have N distinct and ordered elements.

```
(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)     # Example with 7 elements.
```

And we permute them randomly, for example....

```
(3, 2, 5, 4, 1, 7, 6)     # We get one coincidence for the number 4.
```

What is the probability that at least one element matches its original position?

If the question were about the probability that all numbers match, it would be easy, 1/N!

But the probability it's not so easy to calculate because the value at each position depends on the others.

For example, I guess the probability of no coincidences cannot be calculated as

```
((N-1)/N)·((N-2)/(N-1))·((N-3)/(N-2))··· = 1/N
```

Comment: See [Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: The question has been asked and answered on this site numerous times. Here is one place where it is discussed: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4574348/proving-recursive-identity-for-permutations-where-no-element-stays-in-the-same-p?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [the inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle). The number of permutations where a match occurs is

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\cdot (n-k)!$$

Here, $k$ is the number of matching positions, $\binom{n}{k}$ is the number of ways to choose these $k$ positions, $(n-k)!$ is the number of ways to arrange the other $n-k$ elements. The probability is

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1}\binom{n}{k}\cdot (n-k)!}{n!}$$

Or you can use [derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) which already incapsulate this inclusion-exclusion calculation. The answer is $$\frac{1-\text{D}_n}{\text{P}_n}.$$

Comment: Is that formula for 1 match? or for at least 1 match?

Comment: @skan That formula is for at least $1$ match.